# Impossible to disable NX protection in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on Congatec motherboard PA7.
I need to disable the NX protection but it seems an impossible mission.
I wrote `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noexec=off"` in `/etc/default/grub`, then executed `sudo update-grub`.
No success.

Then I entered in GRUB menu after power reset, and I manually wrote the argument "noexec=off" in the command line "linux...", which starts the kernel.
No success.

In both cases, after the boot, the dmesg shows that the NX protection is still enabled:

```
[    0.000000] kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
```

I couldn't find any post of someone with the same problem so I don't find a clue how to solve it.

Just to give a try, I also tried to add the noexec32=off (although my system is 64 bits); no success.

Here are the logfiles downloaded from my system:
boot.log
https://pastebin.com/105rxd5c

dmesg:
https://pastebin.com/zfe4p5k3

kern.log
https://pastebin.com/w4qtMK6E

syslog:
https://pastebin.com/RsS8HeXY

What went wrong and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance.